# Auto clicking on background

Tags: auto, clicking

I work at a chat software LiveChat
It requires really fast clicking to get chats first
What are some ways so I can leave it in the background on a specific tab and it keeps on autoclicking really fast.
Manually Clicking quickly is just not good
Is there a better way rather than to do it from a software?

Comment: Can you please make your question more simple and understandable?

Comment: I mean to say that there’s a specific page where we have trigger chats. In order to do that whoever clicks first gets to have the chat. Best way to do this is keep clicking on that spot really fast so I get the chat first. Its a lot of manual work in order to win those chats. Is there a way to lock the cursor on a specific place and set up some kind of smart clicking system?

Comment: Does that chatbox has any ID or unique class?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.